# Problem with loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

```
no  time  scores
1    10    123
2    11    22
3    12    22
4    50    55
5    60    22
6    70    66
.    .     .
.    .     .
n    n     n
```

Above a the content of my txt file (thousand of lines).

```
1st column - number of samples
2nd column - time (from beginning to end ->accumulated)
3rd column - scores
```

I wanted to create a new file which will be the total of every three sample of the scores divided by the time difference of the same sample.

```
e.g. (123+22+22)/ (12-10) = 167/2 = 83.5
     (55+22+66)/(70-50) = 143/20 = 7.15
```

new txt file

```
83.5
7.15
.
.
.
n
```

so far I have this code:

```
fid=fopen('data.txt')
data = textscan(fid,'%*d %d %d')
time = (data{1})
score= (data{2})
for sample=1:length(score)
     ..... // I'm stucked here ..
end
....
```

Comment: Can you guarantee `n` is a multiple of 3?

Comment: no. if the remaining is less than 3, e.g. 1 or  2 samples, it will just leave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%# Easier to load with importdata
data = importdata('data.txt',' ',1);
%# Get the number of rows
n = size(data,1);
%# Column IDs
time = 2;score = 3;
%# The interval size (3 in your example)
interval = 3;
%# Pre-allocate space
new_data = zeros(numel(interval:interval:n),1);
%# For each new element in the new data
index = 1;
%# This will ignore elements past the closest (floor) multiple of 3 as requested
for i = interval:interval:n
    %# First and last elements in a batch
    a = i-interval+1;
    b = i;
    %# Compute the new data
    new_data(index) = sum( data(a:b,score) )/(data(b,time)-data(a,time));
    %# Increment
    index = index+1;
end
```

Comment: I wonder what is the different between importdata and textscan?

Comment: In `textscan` you need to specify the formatting, `importdata` figures it out (most of the time).

Comment: I wonder if the "data" in the file.data ..refer to the name of the file? data.txt?

Comment: I got this error when implement the code ..Attempt to reference of non-structure array..:(

Comment: No, the `data` is the data component after `importdata`. Can you just type `file = importdata('data.txt');disp(file)` and tell me what the output it?

Comment: it gives many numbers in form of matrix .. without any errors... but when I implement the whole code, it gave this error ..Attempt to reference of non-structure array

Comment: new error comes out .. Index exceeds matrix dimensions. I wonder if this is because the total number of lines of the data is not necessary the multiple of 3?

Comment: Could you send a link to the data file somewhere? Also, if you successfully got the data matrix with `textscan` try using that instead of `importdata`

Comment: I'm not successfully using the textscan as well :( ..
Here is the link of the file http;//www.2shared.com/document/SDQS/data.html

Comment: Why I keep getting this error? :( Index exceeds matrix dimensions ..Error in-> new_data(index) = sum( data(a:b,score) )/(data(b,time)-data(a,time)); ...and this only happened when I change the interval number other than 3 ..

Comment: Thanks Jacob :-) ... this is really great! you helped me a lot...  thank you very much. I have small problem though, it seems when I checked the output of ..it seems that it took the interval of 6 and not 5...

Comment: My apologies!! I didn't check it before posting, try the code now.

Comment: Haha, no problems, glad to help :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are feeling adventurous, here's a vectorized one-line solution using ACCUMARRAY (assuming you already read the file in a matrix variable `data` like the others have shown):

```
NUM = 3;
result = accumarray(reshape(repmat(1:size(data,1)/NUM,NUM,1),[],1),data(:,3)) ...
    ./ (data(NUM:NUM:end,2)-data(1:NUM:end,2))
```

Note that here the number of samples `NUM=3` is a parameter and can be substituted by any other value.

Also, reading your comment above,  if the number of samples is not a multiple of this number (`3`), then simply discard the remaining samples by doing this beforehand:

```
data = data(1:fix(size(data,1)/NUM)*NUM,:);
```

---

Im sorry, here's a much simpler one :P

```
result  = sum(reshape(data(:,3), NUM, []))' ./ (data(NUM:NUM:end,2)-data(1:NUM:end,2));
```

Comment: +1: I've never come across accumarray before, much neater solution than mine.  Thanks @Amro.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is how you would go about to do that in Python. It is probably adaptable to Matlab.

```
import numpy
no, time, scores = numpy.loadtxt('data', skiprows=1).T

 # here I assume that your n is a multiple of 3! otherwise you have to adjust
sums = scores[::3]+scores[1::3]+scores[2::3]
dt = time[2::3]-time[::3]

result = sums/dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `importdata()` function to get your data into your variable called `data`.  Something like this:

```
data = importdata('data.txt',' ', 1)
```

replace `' '` by the delimiter your file uses, the `1` specifies that Matlab should ignore 1 header line.  Then, to compute your results, try this statement:

```
(data(1:3:end,3)+data(2:3:end,3)+data(3:3:end,3))./(data(3:3:end,2)-data(1:3:end,2))
```

This worked on your sample data, should work on the real data you have.  If you figure it out yourself you'll learn some useful Matlab.

Then use `save()` to write the results back to a file.

PS If you find yourself writing loops in Matlab you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Mark: Loops aren't bad always. This has been discussed before in SO. Plus, this solution fixes the interval at 3, ( `data(1:3:end,3) + data(2:3:end) + ... `).

Comment: @Jessy -- how big is your dataset ?

Comment: thousand of lines --- 318687 lines